# How to Create a CAML Query to Retrieve a List Item?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

```
XmlElement camlQuery = Build(); // how to implement this?
```

I have a `SharePoint list` called Authors which has an genericId field.

How to write a CAML query for something like below:

```
Select Name from Authors where genericId = 1
```

Then the camlQuery will be passed to the ListItems sharepoint web service:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx

What I have tried is to create an xml element as below:

```
 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

 XmlElement camlQuery = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");

 camlQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='genericId'/><Value Type='Integer'>9</Value></Lt></Where>";
```

Then this is passed to the GetListItems() service (not sure what's the meaning of Lt or Gt, etc?).

But it throws an exception:

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
```

Many thanks,

Comment: You need to dig into the exception to find the ninner exception that will give you/us more info about what the problem is.  I think lt and gt are operators greater than and less than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be nice to teach you how to write it "yourself" rather then just giving you the right answer.

I assume you have a local farm. Create a view in a sharepoint list and make it return the right result by using filters. Then download this tool http://spm.codeplex.com/ and navigate to you view. Then copy and paste the CAML OF A VIEW into your code. That is it.

P.S. LT stands for less than, GT stands for greater than. You will need Eq (equal) in your case.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can create CAML Queries with the 

[U2U CAML Query Builder for SharePoint 2003 and SharePoint 2007](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx),
the [U2U CAML Query Builder Feature](http://www.u2u.be/Tools/SharePointCamlQueryBuilder.aspx) -
OR you could use [LINQ to SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535491.aspx) as an alternative (if you've got SharePoint 2010)

Answer (score 0):

Check this approach very easy to create caml query even run the query: [Link](http://cawl4sharepoint.com/cawl4sharepoint/cawl_querybuilder/)

```
cawl_QueryBuilder cawl = new cawl_QueryBuilder;
cawl.Where("FirstName","=","Mike");
cawl.Where("Status","!=","Passive");
cawl.Get("Users");

Gridview1.Datasource= cawl.ListItemCollection().GetDataTable();
Gridview1.Databind();
```